# Can i use <ui:repeat> only for returning Data from a list?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

i am new to stackoverflow and i have a simple question but dont know how to search for it correctly.
I want something like the following, with the difference, that the second ui:repeat should not generate more html elements, i want to use it just for defining the id of the img:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bla.aStringlist()}" var="a">
    <ui:repeat value="#{bla.bStringlist()}" var="b">
        <p:graphicImage library="pix" name="/#{a}" onclick="afunction(someString);" id="#{b}"/>
    <ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

So i am searching for something that works like ui:repeat, with this "value" and "var" attribute, but only for returning data :)

Comment: With your code you'll get too many graphicImage. Have you tried with a single repeat, with something like `#{b.field}` or like `#{bla.misteryFunction(b)}` for the name/id. You can also use `c:forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one map instead of two list, you can use c:for.
Here some reference [jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)